Cache or save results of perf report
For large files, perf report takes a while. e.g. around 5 minutes for 500G perf.data. Is there a way to dump (certain states of) perf report to a file, or tell perf to cache something that enables faster invocation of perf report later on?
Note that I dont want to just save the first view of perf report by redirecting to a file perf report > a.txt
